# MVC select model's data from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am passing a model IEnumerable to a view. Appending the model to a dropdownlist

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ddlOffers", new SelectList(Model,"Id","Title"))
 <p id="result"></p>
```

I have javascript on change I am getting value selected

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#ddlOffers").change(function () {
        alert(this.value);
    });
});
</script>
```

It is retrieving the correct value Id. On selecting from the list I want grab the record details from a Model (such as Title,CreatedBy...etc) based on the selection.

How do I select the right data from the Model using value Id selected in the javascript? and should I then append the data to the p tag? Am I on the right track? Or is there a simpler solution?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Your only including a control for one property in your view (the `Id` property which is bound to the dropdownlist). In the `.change()` event, use ajax to pass the selected value to a controller method which returns a partial view of the details based on the selected value and update the DOM with the returned view (refer [jquery.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

suppose your model is

```
public class Model {
 public int Id,
 public string Title,
 public int CreatedBy
 /*Other Properties*/
}
```

when you put it through this statement

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlOffers", new SelectList(Model,"Id","Title"))
```

All you get on the html side and you can check the source of the HTML file is

```
<select>
<option value="1">Title 1</option>
<option value="2">Title 2</option>
<option value="3">Title 3</option>
<option value="4">Title 4</option>
<option value="5">Title 5</option>
</select>
```

So you see the problem in getting other properties is that they dont exist in the HTML page and hence cannot be directly retrieved by the javascript.

1. What you can do instead is put all the data you need in the html attributes in the html option element by creating it manually.

   @foreach(var m in Model)
   {
    @m.Title
   }

now when you will handle the change even the data will be available inside the HTML and hence you will be able to access it. With something like this

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#ddlOffers").change(function () {
        var createdBy = $(this).data('createdBy');
        alert(createdBy);
    });
});
</script>
```

2. Alternatively what you can do is and this approach will only help you if you want to later convert this into a big application.

after selecting the value in the javascript you send a ajax request to another action on your server with will return you all the fields you need back. 

Update:-
3. You can also inject the model serializing it to JSON in the view and then whenever required accessing the info using js. For this i generally use [Newtonsoft Json](https://json.codeplex.com/) (`install-package newtonsoft.json`) then inside the view do something like this

```
<script>
var model = @JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model);
</script>
```

Comment: You mentioned do a ajax request to get other fields. In the controlled I generate a model containing other fields and passing to the view as ToList() as IEnumerable.. if I do foreach loop in the view i see all the fields and data.. but you are saying it is not possible to get other fields without calling another request and passing the id? no way to do something like model[id]?

Answer (score 0):

What `@Html.DropDownList` do is generate html like this:

```
<select id="ddlOffers" name="ddlOffers">
    <option value="somevalue">sometext</option>
    ... for all your options
</select>
```

And if you just need the value selected, there's a shortcut in jquery:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#ddlOffers").change(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
</script>
```

Or if you need anything other than the value, you can get the selected `<option>` itself by

```
<script>
$(function () {
  $("#ddlOffers").change(function () {
     console.log($(this).find("option:selected"));
     console.log($("#ddlOffers option:selected"));  //both of them do the same thing
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The way I have approached this before is to use a form like this:

```
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName",new AjaxOptions{HttpMethod = "POST"}))
            {
                @Html.DropDownList("ddlOffers", new SelectList(Model,"Id","Title"))

                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            }
```

Have the form submit to a controller and dropdown's value set to your ID field and then when it posts back into the controller, get the full object based on ID